# how to do this using correct OOP?

Tags: java, oop

I extended a JPanel for using it as a canvas for drawing.

In the Handler class (the handler for the canvas) I have this code:-

```
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        endingPoint = e.getPoint();
        repaint();

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        startingPoint = e.getPoint();
    }
```

And in the canvas class itself I have something like this (MainFrame is a class extending JFrame and having Handler as an inner class):-

```
    if (MainFrame.paintingShape.equalsIgnoreCase("line"))
    {
        g.drawLine(MainFrame.startingPoint.x, MainFrame.startingPoint.y, ..., ...);
    }
```

But I read somewhere that I should declare all a class`s variables private and all work on variables should be done using methods in the same class.
But I couldn't do that here, how could I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainFrame` class you could have a method `getStartingPoint` that returns (a copy of) `startingPoint`. Same thing for the `paintingShape` variable: replace public access with a `getPaintingShape` method.

Essentially, whenever you have a public field consider replacing it with get/set methods and private access. It makes your code more maintainable in the future.